# "are absolutely"

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

During a recent heated conversation I said "You are absolutely a pedantic snob."

The person I was speaking with corrected me that it should be "You absolutely are"

Lack of self-awareness aside and for the sake of my own personal curiosity, is that a valid placement of an adverb in relation to a verb like "are" or "is"? I know it is unorthodox, but is it technically incorrect? This person frequently makes formalities in language structure out to be actual rules.

Comment: The individual of which you speak was simply being pedantic.

Comment: There's a difference: how much you are determined/known to be a snob versus how much of a snob you are. To see the difference, imagine that *absolutely* refers here to probability or certainty (e.g. 100% sure) versus degree of snobness. The first says that it is 100% sure that you are a snob (of some degree or another). The second says that you are (with unspecified certainty) 100% a snob - an absolute snob. And yes, this is pedantic, and virtually no one recognizes or relies on such a difference.

Comment: Such usage (arguably) belongs to **informal style**, which is not the same as being ungrammatical; see e.g. [CGEL](https://www.amazon.com/Cambridge-Grammar-English-Language/dp/0521431468), pp. 6-11. 'It is not that formal style keeps to the rules and informal style departs from them; rather, formal and informal styles have partially different rules' (p. 8).
Your phrasing is certainly [well attested](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22You+are+absolutely+a%22&btnG=Search&num=100&hl=en&tbs=bkv%3Ap&tbm=bks).

Comment: Adverbs can move around, but to my ears the delay of absolutely puts more emphasis on the adverb, so that the degree of snobbery becomes more important. Sentence two seems matter-of-fact.  It may have to do with the rhythm of the syllables. You/are   ab/so   lute/ly Short and long syllables, iambic.

Comment: The 'absoluteness' should be attached to the word 'pedantic'. 'You are an absolutely pedantic snob.' (If one really wants to be pedantic about it.)

Comment: @Nigel J. I tend to agree. Saying "you are absolutely" something, must surely mean that that is the only thing you are - which is absurd. The person is also, presumably a "man/woman", a "mathematician", a "grandparent" etc. But saying "you are an absolute pedantic snob" means that you are a snob, in an absolute sense of being a snob.

Comment: 'Absolutely' is not a traditional adverb here. It's a pragmatic marker (traditionally a 'sentence adverbial') of emphasis (here, infuriated) synonymous with 'really' or even an exclamation mark or scowl. It's far less common than 'really', perhaps sounding weak/effeminate, and while I don't like it either before or after 'are' here, most people would place 'really' before 'are'.

Comment: The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+are+absolutely%2Cyou+absolutely+are%2Cyou+really+are%2Cyou+are+really&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20absolutely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20absolutely%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20really%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20are%20really%3B%2Cc0) shows no difference for 'you really are/ you are really' but indicates that 'you are absolutely' is far more common than 'you absolutely are'.

Comment: Usually, the point of using the less common word order and the less appropriate word in a sentence like this is irony. The person saying it knows he's saying it in a "snobbish" way. "Here's what a snob (you) sounds like."  "STOP SCREAMING!"

Answer (score 1):

The sentences CAN mean entirely different things.

*"You are absolutely a pedantic snob."*

The word **absolutely** here is simply an intensifier of the insult. The sentence isn't semantically distinct from "You are a pedantic snob." The absolutely serves only to convey the emotion and intensity with which the speaker is communicating.

*"You absolutely are a pedantic snob"* sounds most to me like a rebuttal to a claim that one is not a pedantic snob.

> He: *"I am not a pedantic snob."*
>
> You: *"You absolutely ARE a pedantic snob."* [capitals used for tonal
>   emphasis]

In the case that it is said apropos of nothing, the meanings between the two arrangements are interchangeable.

But suffice it to say, your friend absolutely is an absolutely pedantic snob.